# builtin cd vs /usr/bin/cd

Tags: bash, shell, cd

In Bash:

```bash
$ which cd
/usr/bin/cd
```

```bash
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

What is the difference between them?  
IOW, if *builtin `cd`* (or `/usr/bin/cd`) is called when I type `cd`, what's the point of the existence of `/usr/bin/cd` (or *builtin `cd`*)?

---

As @erik258 said, `/usr/bin/cd` is a shell script.
So it seems that *builtin `cd`* is called when I type `cd`, then what is the point of the existence of `/usr/bin/cd`?

---

CentOS Stream 8

Comment: I've never heard of an executable `/usr/bin/cd`. My Arch Linux system does not have it. It cannot possibly work as a standalone executable either, because it would need to affect the environment of the parent process. What system are you on?

Comment: @Thomas: CentOS Stream 8

Comment: unlike `echo` which could feasibly work as a subprocess, `cd` only works as a builtin because a child process can't change its parent's working directory.  Check `file /usr/bin/cd` and see what kind of file it is.  On osx it's a shell script

Comment: This question has been asked and answered over on [unix.se] already. Arguably it's more on-topic there than here: [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command)

Comment: Stack Overflow's scope is narrowly limited to questions about problems you face in the course of software development. Being curious about something does not constitute (quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) a "practical, answerable question based on a specific problem that you face".